# WPF/XNA animation effect like effect "Vortex" in PowerPoint

Tags: wpf, animation, xna, powerpoint

The interface of my program is a grid of squares (minimum 16). How can I apply to interface elements animation effect like [effect "Vortex"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FWaLkenI39A) in PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use a pixel shader for that.